# How can I add strings to an array in a JSON using node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, discord

I have a discord bot and I want to have an array that has the user ids of people who abuse the volume and music commands so that I can take away their abilities and give them back using commands like `!nomusic` and `!musicback`, but I have no idea how I would make it add or remove their `ids` from an array in the config file. My best guess is to use `fs` and have it push the member's `id` into the array, but I have no idea how I would go about doing this (I'm very new to `node.js` and especially `fs`, so sorry if this is a really easy thing to do and is really dumb to ask)

So far this is how far I've gotten(lots of the program not included so it's easier to read)

```
function readNoMusicJSON() {
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./nomusic.json"));
}

var badmusicusers = readNoMusicJSON();

function nomusicsfoyou(badmusicusers, userId) {
    return nomusic.concat([userId]);
}

function saveNoMusicFile(badmusicusers) {
    fs.writeFileSync("./nomusic.json");
}
bot.on('message', async message => {
//some code ommited due to lack of importance
var args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);    
var command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
switch(command){
    case"music":
        if(badmusicusers.find(id=>id == message.author.id)) return;
        // more ommitted code that don't matter
        break;
    case "nomusic":
        let sadmusicboi = message.mentions.members.first();
        badmusicusers = nomusicsfoyou((badmusicusers, sadmusicboi.id));
        saveNoMusicFile(badmusicusers);
        break;
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? Any example of the object/array you want to manipulate? Adding a string to an object is as simple as: `exampleObject.thing = '!nomusic';`

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a list of bannedUsers in your config bannedUsers.json file.

```
["user-id-1", "user-id-2"]
```

On Startup of the program, you read the file into a variable:

```
function readBannedUsers() {
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./bannedUsers.json"));
}

var bannedUsers = readBannedUser();
```

Whenever you want to ban a user:

```
function banUser(bannedUsers, userId) {
     return bannedUsers.concat([userId]);
}

function saveBannedUsers(bannedUsers) {
     fs.writeFileSync("./bannedUsers.json");
}

bannedUsers = banUser(bannedUsers, "user-3");
saveBannedUsers(bannedUsers);
```

That's all.

Comment: Okay I got all this but I don't know how I could get it to check if the user's ID is in the array. I've tried `if(readNoMusicJSON().find(id=>id == message.author.id)) return;` but this doesn't seem to work (I changed some of the name to make it a bit easier to read for me, readNoMusicJSON is the same as the readBannedUsers function in your answer)

Comment: Okay, I thought of another thing where i replaces the readNoMusicJSON() with "badmusicusers" which is my program's equivalent of the bannedUsers  variable in your answer, but that doesn't seem to work either.